# Visual Studio Run Guard External Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2012, guard

I have set up a basic guard file to watch for css and js in my .net project.

If i do this in the CMD to the project and type "guard" it works great.

How would I get this to be a external command in visual studio? I would need a .bat or .exe to run in the $(project) and pass the guard argument.

What am I missing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Windows guy, but you probably want to start Guard in the background with a command like: `START /B CMD /C CALL "foo.bat"`

You probably also want to set the starting directory to where the `Gemfile` is, and run `bundle exec guard` as the command.